# What kind of red/green/black, spiny caterpillar is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

It's red and lime green with black on its back and a few white spots as well. Found in Tulsa, Oklahoma (USA).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a greenish variant of [***Hemileuca maia***](http://mothphotographersgroup.msstate.edu/species.php?hodges=7730) – the **Buck Moth**, which according to [here](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/misc/moths/buck_moth.htm) does occur in Oklahoma. This source also suggests that touching the caterpillar (or its relatives) is a bad idea...

[image]

<sup>Source: [statebystategardening](http://statebystategardening.com/images/uploads/article_uploads/2013_Feb_news_3-D2.jpg)</sup>